# Can I build mailing list software on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to search if it's legal or GAE will be able to support sending/receiving email just fine with mailing list kind of operation -- but so far I couldn't find anything useful.

Do you know if this is permissible or possible? Or even a good idea?

I'm thinking simple mailing list software for a single owner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can build that, and in the GAE documentation is a good chapter about how to do that:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html

If the fairly high quotas for sending mail:

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail

are not enough, you can ask for an increase. Not sure if that will cost you money.

Answer (score 3):

App Engine does support sending and receiving email (see [sending mail in App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) and [receiving mail in App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html)). The [App Engine program policy](http://code.google.com/appengine/program_policies.html) prohibits sending spam emails (see the "Prohibited Actions" section), but as long as you are sending legitimate emails, there should not be a problem.

That said, if this is secondary to your main application (i.e. you just want to provide a mailing list as a support forum, for example), it may be easier to just use [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview) for that functionality.